# Spring Data JPA, Hibernate, @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) and org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, lazy-loading

In [Employee and Phone example](https://github.com/paulvi/spring-boot-querydsl/commit/596415fc1df354ca3002c74cfe1c07c4b74e62c8)

[image]

How to make Hibernate Lazy initialization to work (within Spring Boot)?

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at com.example.domain.Employee_$$_jvstb7e_2.toString(Employee_$$_jvstb7e_2.java) ~[bin/:na]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at com.example.domain.Phone.toString(Phone.java:13) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.example.SpringBootQuerydslTestBean$1.run(SpringBootQuerydslTestBean.java:49) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

[Java code](https://github.com/paulvi/spring-boot-querydsl/commit/596415fc1df354ca3002c74cfe1c07c4b74e62c8)

```
public class Phone {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Employee owner;
```

P.S.
Some advises to use `FetchType.EAGER` like in [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654818/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-sessi),
but making Lazy loading work (within Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA) is exactly my goal.

Comment: have you tried current_session_context_class --> thread?

Comment: Do you have repository.impl classes?? You can fetch data from JPA query.

Comment: Create a proper `toString` that doesn't include the back reference. The issue is you are logging something (I guess)... Again potentially dangerous as when it would work you probably would run into a stack overflow exception due to Pone referencing `Employee` which has a `toString` probably referencing `Phone` again and gain and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to M. Deinum for hint.

This particular case 
was solved by adding `toString()` in `Employee` to re-define over Lombok `toString()`

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }
```

also [specifying exactly Fetch type](https://github.com/paulvi/spring-boot-querydsl/commit/767f46c62a7005d49c0c2b7b6a360c2e7b352807)

code at https://github.com/paulvi/spring-boot-querydsl

Comment: You could also use Lombok and just explicitly exclude the `employee` field from `Phone` which should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the Lombok instruction @Data, instead of it, use @Getter and @Setter, 
Follow javadocs from @Data:

> Equivalent to @Getter @Setter @RequiredArgsConstructor @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode.

The instruction @ToString generate a implementation of toString method for entire class, so in your JPA return needs to have data for all the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the childs from the proxy when the current session is detached ,
you can get the lazy childs in the same session .

Comment: How to control sessions(that are Hibernate things) from Spring Boot that uses Spring Data repositories over JPA?